# Azure function connectionstring for Azure SQL trough VNet

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I would like to know how to access my Azure SQL database in a secure way from my Azure Function App, meaning not via public Internet.

I have an Function App (Function App Plan - standard tier), using VNET/Gateway integration. I have specified a service EndPoint for Microsoft.SQL ... I enabled the Virtual network access on Azure SQL database ....

When the Azure function tries to connect to the sql db, it uses the 'normal' connectionstring, which includes the sql database server name as dns label, then I get the error that my ip address is not allowed access. The ip address is the outbound IP address of the Azure function app.

I think this error implies that the function app is trying to connect to the Azure SQL database via public internet. The idea is that this requests should reach the Azure SQL database through the VNet.

My guess is that the connection string should be different. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can simply create a point-to-site private VPN connection from your Function to your virtual network using VNET integration: https://codehollow.com/2016/12/connect-azure-app-service-to-virtual-network/

Comment: Andres, thanks for the excellent pointer. That helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When the Azure function tries to connect to the sql db, it uses the
>   'normal' connectionstring, which includes the sql database server name
>   as dns label, then I get the error that my ip address is not allowed
>   access.

When we try to connect the sql database, the network traffic will **go through the Internet**.
Because Azure service resources can be secured to your virtual network. Securing service resources to a virtual network provide improved security by **fully removing public Internet access to resources**, and **allowing traffic only from your virtual network**.

Like this, Internet network traffic will can't access this service(SQL database):
[image]

If you want to connect Azure function app and Azure SQL database, we should deploy Azure function app in Azure Vnet, we should use App Service Environment to deploy it.

More information about App Service environments, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro).

Comment: Thanks Jason, yes this is the exact scenario I'm working on. I used an App Service Plan standard with a Gateway for the Azure function App. In this case the traffic would go trough the gateway right? The question then is .. what is the approriate connection string to use, or .. how to connect to the Sql Database from the function app.

Comment: Thanks for the update in your response. Unfortunately the ASE pricetag is high to start with. For our usecase this is not an option.

Comment: Sorry @jason-ye-msft, so this means that the only way to allow access to Azure SQL in this scenario is to deploy the functions app in ASE? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work out-of-the-box now.

If your function app is in standard tier, and if you have enable VNET integration, the connection to SQL Server via its public server name just works fine.